# Highcharts bar and scatter series not lining up

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart using highcharts that includes both a column series and a scatter series with a custom point marker. The series will contain slightly different sets of data, but will overlap for the most part and will always have the same x-axis values.
I've set it up, but the problem is that it's not lining up perfectly. Some of the scatter series' points are shifted one or two pixels to the left of the corresponding bar.
Any ideas about how to fix this?

```
{
        chart: {
            animation: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 1
        },
        series: [{
            type: "column",
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointWidth: 20,
            name: "col"
        },
        {
            type: "scatter",
            states: { hover: { enabled: false } },
            marker: { symbol: 'url(symbol.png)' }
        }]
    }
```

And here's a screenshot of what's happening:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a bug, also with standard markers, so I've decided to report it to our developers https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1843